Помогите разорбрать ошибку: E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'pdInput'
В библиотеке Delphi 12 есть все компоненты поскольку подсказки работают и код написан соответственно, но ошибка выдается на pdInput после запятой после параметра DataType.
Код касается добавление параметра в AQOQuery
Где может быть ошибка и как ее исправить?
DM1.AQSt1.Parameters.CreateParameter('VSTValue',ftFloat,pdInput, 10, VST);


Модуль Data.Win.ADODB подключен?
